# How to run cargo tests sequentially?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

There are several tests under `proxy/v1_specific`. I have to run them in sequential, since these tests have some influence with each other.

```
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test1
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test2
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test3
```

I wonder if there are some magic arguments `--magic=level` that

```
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific --magic=1
# Equivalence
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test1
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test2
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test3
```

and

```
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific --magic=2
# Equivalence
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test1::subtest1
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test1::subtest2
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test2::subtest1
cargo test --package tests --test proxy v1_specific::test3::subtest1
```

I know by `--job=1`, I can run them sequentially. However, I may want all subtests in `v1_specific::test1` to be run in parallel.

Comment: @JonasFassbender No, I still want subtests inside `v1_specific::test1` to be run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Use --test-threads=1 or use Mutex to manually run the function sequentially.

Comment: I'm not sure a mutex would work, as different test files are usually compiled into separate binaries and thus do not share the same statics. However, a file lock should work.